# to delete a file in ubuntu

Tags: delete

I wanted to recover some files but while recovering them I made a folder that used up all of my disk space and space free is 0 bytes. How can I delete it as it is not allowing me to delete it?

Comment: what is the error?

Answer (score 4):

`sudo rm -rf <your folder path>`

What this command does is force the recursive removal of all files and directories within the specified directory, as well as the directory itself.

**Note:** Please make sure to backup any needed files, and be **very careful** when using this command! Using this on any system directory or files will, in essence, destroy your system!